# How to run Jasmine tests in watch mode for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine

I have a Node.js app using TypeScript and now I want Jasmine to run tests automatically each time I make changes in .ts files. So I'm just trying to find an appropriate command to be run as `npm test` in command line or a package that can watch my .ts files compile them on changes and run jasmine. Does anybody know a solution for it?

Comment: What is your current `test` command?  IE, in your `package.json`, what is `test` in the `scripts` block?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way I found is

installing dependencies: `npm install --save-dev jasmine-ts nodemon`

initializing jasmine: `node_modules/.bin/jasmine-ts init`

In the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "nodemon --ext ts --exec 'jasmine-ts \"src/**/*.spec.ts\"'"
}
```

**Edit:** the above solution doesn't work as of the 11th of Apr, 2019. I published a modified working example at https://github.com/erosb/ts-node-jasmine-example

Comment: Actually had problem with that on Windows (couldn't find jasmine-ts). Had to split it up into test and test-watch:
"test": "jasmine-ts \"src/**/jasmine-test.spec.ts\"",
"test-watch": "nodemon --ext ts --exec \"npm test \""

Answer (score 1):

This may be done with two commands launched in separate terminals. Assuming packages are installed in global mode.

First command launches TypeScript compiler in watch mode:

`tsc --watch`

The second starts nodemon that watches .js files and restarts on changes. Each time it executes jasmine test runner:

`nodemon --ext js --exec 'jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=jasmine.json'`

This solution is fast enough though it also has a drawback of running in two terminals. So it is not ideal but the best I've found so far.

As a result scripts section in package.json looks like:

```
"scripts": {
  /* ... */
  "watch": "tsc --watch",
  "test": "nodemon --ext js --exec 'jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=jasmine.json'",
  "devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www"
},
```

`devstart` also works in couple with `watch` restarting server each time .ts files are changed (after they are compiled to .js).

Answer (score 1):

Previously described methods either did not work, or were slow to compile code. Here is my attempt to solve this, both fast and convenient, works great for me. The only downside is that jasmine would not know which tests are affected by TS recompilation and would run all the tests.

```bash
yarn add tsc-watch --dev
```

```bash
yarn run tsc-watch --onSuccess "yarn run jasmine --config=jasmine.json"
```

NPM version:

```bash
npm -i tsc-watch
```

```bash
npm run tsc-watch --onSuccess "npm run jasmine --config=jasmine.json"
```

In my case I needed to correctly map TS paths. The full command looks like this:

```bash
yarn run tsc-watch --onSuccess \
     "node -r tsconfig-paths/register node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine \
     --config=jest/jasmine.json --require=dist/jest/setup.js $targetFile"
```

jasmine.json

```json
{
  "spec_dir": "dist/src",
  "spec_files": ["**/*.e2e.js", "**/*.unit.js", "**/*.spec.js", "**/*.test.js"],
  "env": {
    "random": false
  }
}
```

Just an example, please adjust to your needs.

[tsc-watch](https://github.com/gilamran/tsc-watch) starts a TypeScript compiler with --watch parameter, with the ability to react to successful compilation and start tests.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`jasmine-node`](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node).  I don't think that jasmine itself has a watch option.

```
npm i -g jasmine-node
```

Assuming that your `test` command in your `package.json` `scripts` block is something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jasmine some-directory-or-glob-pattern"
    ...
}
```

Use `jasmine-node` and add the `--autotest` and `--watch` flags to that command:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jasmine-node --autotest --watch some-directory-or-glob-pattern"
    ...
}
```

Comment: It looks like in this case I still need a kind of a preprocessor to precompile .ts files before running tests. Does this package have any such options? I can make nodemon to watch my files and run jasmine on changes so this is not a problem. I even can make it run tsc first to compile all .ts to .js and then run jasmine but this is not the same as compiling .ts in watch mode because it compiles all files in the project directory and that takes quite a while. I'm looking for a fast seamless way of running tests to improve my workflow.

Comment: Ah, your _tests_ are in TypeScript.  I didn't get that.  Then my answer will not help you.  Maybe you should check out Jest instead?  Jasmine-like syntax, very nice, and there's a TS version: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest

Comment: Thank you, I will pay my attention to it.